# [VsCode Remote SSH]How to solve 'Could not establish connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Downloading VS Code Server failed'?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[**Problem Description**]

When I work on setting VS Code remote ssh on a new server, I find this error:

> "Could not establish connection to "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX":Downloading VS Code Server failed - please install either curl or wget on the remote".

However, **I have curl and wget installed on my remote server.** And the network connection on my remote server is also fine. Following some tutorials in the web, I download vscode-server on the remote side by:

`wget vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:<commit-id>/server-linux-x64/stable`

and then extract it, copy to `~/.vscode-server/bin/<commit-id>/`, and replaced the files there.The error message disappears.

It works fine at the beginning, but everytime I close and reopen project on the remote server, VsCode  would start to download remote server automatically and then collapse to so called "please install either curl or wget on the remote". Moreover, the **VsCode built-in terminal** would fail to no cuda environement or GPU driver error(Cuda and driver work fine on remote side) even if I fortunately connect to remote at chance.

[**Environment**]

Local Side:
MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 + VsCode 1.50.1 + Remote-SSH Extension(Microsoft) 0.6.1

Remote Side
Ubuntu 18.04.5 + Wget 1.19.4 + Curl 7.58.0

[**Log**]

```
[10:57:03.119] Neither curl nor wget is installed - can't download the Server
[10:57:03.125] Resolver error: Error: Downloading VS Code Server failed - please install either curl or wget on the remote.
    at Function.ServerInstallError (/Users/XXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:1:82253)
    at /Users/XXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:1:79401
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/XXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:1:80935)
    at I (/Users/XXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:107056)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async /Users/XXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:104971
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/XXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:110308)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/Users/XXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:108372)
    at async /Users/XXX/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.61.0/out/extension.js:127:129627
[10:57:03.131] ------




[10:57:03.428] "install" terminal command done
[10:57:03.429] Install terminal quit with output:
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because there are so many vscodes open on the remote server that you need to kill all the VSCODE processes on the remote server and then try to connect again or make a new connection, save host information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [IdollronMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17585036/idollronman) for the helpful hints!

I encountered a similar issue and discovered that there were multiple vscode-server processes running on the server. To check for these processes, you can use the following command:

```
ps uxa
```

You will likely find numerous vscode-server processes listed. To resolve the issue, you can try the following steps:

Use the command below to find the relevant processes and terminate them:

```
ps uxa | grep .vscode-server | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

This command essentially finds the processes and terminates them.

Alternatively, you can manually terminate the vscode-server processes.

Once you have terminated the processes, restart your vscode remote session.

If anyone has insights into why this error occurs or alternative solutions, please feel free to contact me or discuss it here!

I hope this helps!

(This is not a once-for-all solution.)